# Privacy policy to be hosted for Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to host the privacy policy created for my windows 8 metro application over the internet. Any way in which i can host HTML file containing such the information for free?

Comment: Don't you have a homepage for your app at all? (Don't you need to provide a description page and a support contact page in the app description?) You can almost certainly set up a blog with a free blog provider and add the privacy policy as a static page to your blog, e.g. WordPress.com. (I can't vouch for MS accepting RajanSoftware.wordpress.com URLs though - they may want something more formal-looking.)

Comment: @Rup - regarding the URL you are suggesting - MS accepted mine, so yours would seem fine. I've got mine at "somename.homedns.org/myappname" (names changed to protect the innocent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Heuer has an article on using Azure Websites to create a free marketing website for your app which could include a privacy policy, it's available at [Using Azure Web Sites to market your Windows App](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/09/26/use-azure-free-web-site-for-windows-store-app-content.aspx).

Comment: I will try this out and check if Microsoft accepts this. However this seems to be a good option.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't get text message from Azure website to register for trial version. :( Tried the same for last 2 days but no luck. Now it doesn't even take my mobile number.

Comment: I could successfully create the website. Thanks for the help

Comment: Use any free blogging website to create a privacy policy e.g. wordpress.com